# Como gerar classes compiladas e manter os .java no maven?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2.2, maven, minify-maven-plugin

Galera sempre que faço o maven install ele compila as classes e gera o xxx.class, até ai tudo bem.
Gostaria de saber se é possível gerar o .class e manter também todos os .java, na aplicação que estou fazendo vou precisar mostrar a página e o código exemplo feito para criar a mesma logo queria ler e pegar por stream os .java e mostrar na tela.

Meu problema é que só tenho os .class depois do maven install, alguém poderia me ajudar?

Comment: Você pode usar o [Assembly Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/) ou o [Resouces Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/) para fazer isso.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inclua o seguinte *resource* no **pom.xml**:

```
    <resource>
        <directory>${basedir}/src/main/java</directory>
    </resource>
```

Veja mais ou menos como ficaria na estrutura geral do arquivo:

```
<project>
    ...
        <build>
            ...
                 <resources>
                    <resource>
                        <directory>${basedir}/src/main/java</directory>
                    </resource>
                </resources>
        </build>
</project>
```

Se quiser saber mais sobre o plugin *resources*: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/

E quando precisar consultar a estrutura geral do arquivo para saber em que local uma seção ou plugin pode ser configurado: https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html

Comment: amigo, colocando isso ele vai gerar os .java nesse diretório ?

Comment: @MarcusVinicius Não. Ele vai copiar ("gerar") os .java **deste** local **para** o local destino do build. Na prática, os arquivos *.java* estarão no destino junto com os seus respectivos arquivos *.class*. Faça o teste. Experimente!

Comment: Deu certo aqui, obrigado mesmo cara salvo minha vida hehe.

Comment: Precisar de alguma coisa também é só me chamar, abraço.

Comment: @MarcusVinicius Você pode votar e aceitar as respostas que "salvaram a sua vida" :-)

Comment: vou votar hehehe, na vdd surgiu outro problema, ele gero o .java, dei um maven install e vi la, porém quando vou subir o widfly, com essa configuração no pom
ele me da esse erro

java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: is parameter must not be null java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: is parameter must not be null

Comment: @MarcusVinicius Testei aqui e pra mim funcionou normal no Wildfly. Deve ser algum outro problema. Experimente remover a configuração sem fazer mais nenhuma outra alteração, dar clean no projeto e fazer install e deploy novamente - creio que o erro vai persistir (por estar relacionado a outra coisa e não a esta configuração).

Comment: Você ta certo man, era um erro aqui mesmo, deu certo o que você falo hehe, como que eu voto que salvaram minha vida?

Comment: amigo, você sabe porque quando eu coloco essa configuração os meus .xml no meta-inf somem ?

Comment: @MarcusVinicius E aí, problema resolvido?